What is the Best Approach to Model Relationships in Prisma for MongoDB with Stripe Integration
I am trying to build a general purpose website with stripe that can accept one time payments and subscriptions, also handle refunds and invoices.
The app also will have a dashboard to view and manage these data.
I am struggling to build the relationship between these models, but I have reached to this point at the moment, also unsure if this is a good approach longterm for example if this brings too many unnecessary relationships between models.
I have emitted fields that are not necessary for this question, to make the relations as clear as possible.
model User {
    id            String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    orders        Order[]
    subscriptions Subscription[]
    invoices      Invoice[]
    payments      Payment[]
}

model Order {
    id       String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    payments Payment[]
    userId   String    @db.ObjectId
    user     User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model Subscription {
    id       String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    payments Payment[]
    invoices Invoice[]
    userId   String    @db.ObjectId
    user     User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model Charge {
    id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    paymentId String  @db.ObjectId
    payment   Payment @relation(fields: [paymentId], references: [id])
}

model Refund {
    id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    paymentId String  @db.ObjectId
    payment   Payment @relation(fields: [paymentId], references: [id])
}

model Payment {
    id             String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    charges        Charge[]
    refunds        Refund[]
    orderId        String?       @unique @db.ObjectId
    order          Order?        @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
    subscriptionId String?       @unique @db.ObjectId
    subscription   Subscription? @relation(fields: [subscriptionId], references: [id])
    invoiceId      String?       @unique
    invoice        Invoice?      @relation(fields: [invoiceId], references: [id])
    userId         String        @db.ObjectId
    user           User          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model Invoice {
    id             String        @id @map("_id")
    payments       Payment[]
    subscriptionId String?       @unique @db.ObjectId
    subscription   Subscription? @relation(fields: [subscriptionId], references: [id])
    userId         String        @db.ObjectId
    user           User          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}


What is your actual question? What are you having problems with?

Seems redundant making four tables when you can make two table and add a column in payment.
Adjust the Payment table to add transactionType.
This transactionType will replace Tables (Order, Charge, Refund). Subscription can be replace with an Account Table . I will assume one Stripe User can add multiple accounts. You will need an Account Table Linked to your User Table and all Transactions will link through the Payment table . With a Daily Transaction Table which is seperate, to store Failed and Successsful Transaction.
You might need to add another column to indicate successful transaction in Payment. I prefer Payment Table to be renamed to Transaction Table.
Account Table should have a Seperate Account Group table if you want to model your database further by linking dependant accounts between multiple Users.
model Payment {
id             String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
charges        Charge[]
refunds        Refund[]
orderId        String?       @unique @db.ObjectId
order          Order?        @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
subscriptionId String?       @unique @db.ObjectId
subscription   Subscription? @relation(fields: [subscriptionId], references: [id])
invoiceId      String?       @unique
invoice        Invoice?      @relation(fields: [invoiceId], references: [id])
userId         String        @db.ObjectId
user           User          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
transactionType String       @.............(Ex:(R:Refund),(D,Deposit),(P,Payment))


I don't understand why would i change the representation of an order to become a transaction?
Can you also please elaborate on "a stripe user can have multiple accounts"? Shouldn't there be only one account per user? I am thinking this account table redundant.

Sorry but this is from a banking perspective. One stripe user can have multiple accounts to pay using the strip no. You have a master identifier there any accounts will be linked to your master ID.

It does not really create redundant data as U have a master file with basic details and the main identifier number or alphanumeric. Whereas any tables thereafter will reference from the master table. This is slightly redundant but for banking interfaces the importance is rollback privileges and sharding of your database is easier. It's also highly scalable as most data are in specific tables for programs to use. But for stripe you might use a simpler version. If it fits your requirement that one stripe account has one account. You also need an identifier code to state if the account status

You can enhance some tables for more details because in payments systems the key is not to prevent redundancies but to capture all the required data for reversing transactions. Columns that add transaction status. Ur order table should be named transaction table. The invoice table is not necessary as you can perform a derivation from the transaction table. Of course all my tables are as per banking regulations, these are what banks do. It's up to you if you want to reinvent the wheel it's not wrong. If Ur database can satisfy the requirements Its fine
